# Gradle долго собирает проект при подключенном 4g модеме

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Всем привет, такая проблема:
Если к компьютеру подключить 4g модем (или телефон через USB), это увеличивает время сборки Gradle в Android Studio с 4-6 секунд до 2 минут.

Версия AS 2.1.3, Gradle 2.14.1.

В чем может быть дело?

**Обновление**

Если вытащить модем во время сборки проекта, Gradle перестает тупить и программа запускается мгновенно. Как сделать так, чтобы Gradle игнорировал модем? Offline мод в настройках Gradle и Compiler не помогают.

Comment: а если *не подключать*, то на компьютере нет доступа в интернет?

Comment: вы бы как минимум посмотрели в логе сборки (Gradle Log вкладка в самом низу, справа в Android Studio) какой шаг сборки на столько удлинняется

Comment: to metalurgus: именно.

Comment: to xkor: бОльшую часть времени занимает этот шаг - Gradle build using tasks: [:desktop:asseble, :core:assemble]

Comment: похоже, когда есть интернет, градл пытается обновить репозитории, и это происходит долго из за *медленного* интернета. Можете попробовать запретить градлу вообще обновлять что-либо. Не помню, как это делается, но гугл знает.

Comment: например так - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33130403/5292979

Comment: интернет не медленный. Offline work в настройках Gradle стоит, но это никак не влияет.

Comment: модемный интернет хоть и не медленный, но джиттер может быть очень большим. То есть, качать можно на десятках мегабайт, а вот собственно сам запрос идет долго (проще говоря - пинги длинные). В результате, несколько десятков мелких запросов будут выполнятся очень долго.

Comment: to KoVadim: Возможно, допустим проблема в интернете. (Хотя пинг тоже низкий, около 20 мс в спидтесте). Как тогда задать в настройках градла, чтоб он не лез в интернет? Почему offline мод не помогает?

Comment: я не знаю. я давно с ним не работаю